# UIPanGestureRecognizer not working on iOS 13.0

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ios13

I am setting UIPanGestureRecognizer on my view and my code working on iOS version before 13.0 but in 13.0 it is not working and also I debugged my code it is running all fine but it is not translating anything.

Following is the way of setting UIPanGestureRecognizer on my view namely viewContentBG

```
        let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePan(recognizer:)))
        recognizer.delegate = self
        viewContentBG.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        viewContentBG.addGestureRecognizer( recognizer)
```

Now after setting delegate i am getting my recogniser called. but following code is not working on iOS 13, however it is working fine on all versions before 13.0

```
if recognizer.state == .changed {
            
            
            let velocity = recognizer.velocity(in: self.viewContentBG)
            
            translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.viewContentBG)
                        
                 
                 if( (velocity.x > 0 && self.viewContentBG.frame.origin.x < self.viewContentBG.frame.size.width / 3.0)){
                     
                     let movedPoint = CGPoint(x: originalCenter.x+translation.x, y: originalCenter.y)
                    
                     self.viewContentBG.center = movedPoint
                     
                     self.btnLeftAction1.frame.origin.x = 0
                     
                     self.btnLeftAction1.frame.size.width = 0
                     
                     self.btnLeftAction2.frame.origin.x = 0
                     
                     self.btnLeftAction2.frame.size.width = self.viewContentBG.frame.origin.x
                     

                    
                   
                     
                 }
```

> From above code following lines are most important but it is not working on 13.0 and higher versions. the view (viewContentBg) gets
> move a little from wrong directions some times and gets back to its
> original position and sometimes it really does not move a little.

```
let movedPoint = CGPoint(x: originalCenter.x+translation.x, y: originalCenter.y)
                    
                     self.viewContentBG.center = movedPoint
```

> I can suspect there is some sort of new restriction in 13.0 and higher
> versions of iOS for using  UIPanGestureRecognizer, but I really do not
> know what is the main reason which is causing it not working
> correctly. Please help me I am stuck in it. and its kinda main feature
> of my app. :(

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own question, may be it will be useful for someone.

With so many new changes in iOS13 the way of handling Auto-layout is also changed a little bit. So after some research and debugging I found out that gesture is working and gets detected by the view but the view was making wrong movements (not as per my code says)

the Main problem was that I have a view constrained with the outer view. and I was applying pangesture into inner view. The inner view was the one I wanted to translate with user gesture.

so i set one property to true on my inner view and all gets working as expected. following is the property that I set to true.....

```
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

So in iOS13 the auto-layout constraints are more phenomena